# I have got paid or I got paid?

Tags: tense

I have received my last month salary and I want to give a receipt to my employer. Should I write “I have got paid for last month”? Or “I got paid for last month”?

Answer (score 1):

A more natural phrasing might be "I have been paid." But in a receipt you want to be a little more formal, and write something like "This confirms I have received payment in the amount of *€X* for the month of February 2021."

Comment: Thanks randomhead for your answer. What if you need to send a text to him via cellphone, would you rather “I have got paid” or “I got paid”?

Comment: @Kevin probably "I have been paid" or "I received last month's salary."